# Passing the dimension of an Array as a Parameter in C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and am trying to implement a versatile RandomVar class along with some methods for computing common statistics as practice. I'd like to be able form the arbitrary Joint probability RandomVariable from its components by instantiating a new variable of dimension N where N is passed into the constructor. I'd like to implement random Var X as two one dimensional lists of doubles, and the randomVar XY not as two lists of length n^2, but as a randomVar of type double[][] which otherwise can still use all of the same methods (ExpectedValue, Covariance, etc).

I'm having a lot of trouble implementing this. Other than the first naive approach (which had lots of copy and pasting), I've tried inheriting from a base RandomVar class into a JointRandomVar class -- still a lot of copy-pasting. Now I'm trying to the probabilities and outcomes arrays of Class RandomVar as Generics of type List -- this however produces a lot of problems as I can't figure out how to write the methods in an adaptable way (The std_Dev method can't iterate over the way it needs to in general -- so I need some flexible way to define the method so that if the "dimension" of the random Var is 2, the std_Dev method will do a double loop, or flatten out the array for the process of iterating).

Wanting some design help from more experienced programmers -- is having the probabilities/outcomes arrays List the best way to pass a parameter like this?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

EDIT: Here is the the version of the code for all doubles, so people can read it since the un-updated version seemed more confusing to people. I'd like to be able to have all of these methods work on objects of type double[] for any dimension of array, and it to be possible to instantiate the class with _values and _probs having any dimension.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chapter_3_GUI
{
    class RandomVar
    {
        private double[] _values;
        private double[] _probs;
        private double _mean;
        private double _stddev;
        private int _length;
        private double _evalue;

        public RandomVar(double[] values, double[] probs)
        {
            _values = values;
            _probs = probs;
            _mean = meanCalc(_values);
            _stddev = stddevCalc(_values, _mean);
            _length = _values.Length;
            _evalue = expectedVal(_probs, _values, _length);
        }

        public double[] Values
        {
            get { return _values; }
            set { _values = value; }
        }

        public double Mean
        {
            get { return _mean; }
        }

        public double Stdev
        {
            get { return _stddev; }
        }

        public static double meanCalc(double[] var)
        {
            double mean = var.Sum();
            return mean;
        }

        public static double stddevCalc(double[] var, double mean)
        {
            double[] varianceArr = new double[var.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i <= var.Length; i++)
                varianceArr[i] = (var[i] - mean) * (var[i] - mean);
                double variance = varianceArr.Sum();
                double stddev = Math.Sqrt(variance);
                return stddev;
            { 

            }
        }

        public static double[][] multiplyProbs(RandomVar X, RandomVar Y, double[][] cprobMatrix)
        {
            double[][] probArr = new double[X._length][Y._length];
            for (int i=0; i <= probArr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j =0; j <= probArr.Length; j++)
                {
                    probArr[i][j] = Y._probs[j] * cprobMatrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            return probArr;
        }

        public static RandomVar multiplyVars(RandomVar X, RandomVar Y, Func<double,double> f)
        {
            double[][] productArr = new double[X._length][Y._length];
            for (int i=0; i<= productArr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j <= productArr.Length; i=j++)
                {
                    productArr[i][j] = f(X._values[i], Y._values[j]);
                }
            }
            double[][] probArr = multiplyProbs(X, Y, cprobMatrix);
            RandomVar product = new RandomVar(productArr, probArr);
            return product;
        }

        public static double expectedVal(double[] _probs, double[] _values, int _length)
        {
            double[] expectedArr = new double[_length];
            for (int i = 0; i <= expectedArr.Length; i++)
            {
                expectedArr[i] = _probs[i] * _values[i];
            }
            double evalue = expectedArr.Sum();
            return evalue;

        }

        public static double covarianceCalc(RandomVar X, RandomVar Y, Func<double, double> f)
        {
            RandomVar VarXY = multiplyVars(X, Y, f);
            double correlation = expectedVal(VarXY._probs, VarXY._values, VarXY._length);
            double covariance = correlation - (X._mean * Y._mean);
            return covariance;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably get more help by including your efforts so far (even if it isn't working) than describing what you're wanting.

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to tell what you've got just from a natural language description. Consider including your code in your question.

Comment: Alright, I added the code. There is lots of vestigial stuff here, since originally I just had the RandomVar probs/value arrays as type double[]

Comment: _"some methods haven't yet been updated"_ makes he code almost useless.

Comment: Why do you have a `<T>`  in the fist place and what types do you expect to use for it?  The whole thing looks like it is for `double` only. You can't make `double + T` work.

Comment: `new double[X._length][y._length]` isn't going to work, Use the `[,]` variation for arrays.

Comment: I expect to only use double[], double[][], double[][][] and so on depending on how many different randomVars are being joined together. That way multiply randomVar could instantiate a new randomVar with T=double[], if it were joining two random Vars X and Y. 

the goal is a k-dimensional multiply -- where the _probs and _arrays are k dimensional matrices if the randomVar is formed by joining k random vars -- and the methods will work by flattening it out/treating it as one long array of size n^k (so it can be iterated over like any other randomvar).

Comment: Just a note. Dont use `var` as variable name. `var` is an implicit type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the cardinality of each dimension going to be the same? Your comment about *"treating it as one long array of size n^k"* suggests it is. That is, `n` is the length of value/probability pairs in each dimension.

The other question I have is, what is the reasoning behind passing the values and probabilities in two different arrays? If it were me, I'd declare a `struct` that contains the pairs, e.g.:

```
struct ValueProbPair
{
    public readonly double Value;
    public readonly double Probability;

    public ValueProbPair(double value, double probability)
    {
        Value = value;
        Probability = probability;
    }
}
```

Finally, as far as your specific question goes…well, it's not clear what the *specific* question is. You seem to have a *broad* question regarding a flexible way to implement this.

It seems to me that the biggest challenge here (i.e. the roadblock with the least intuitively obvious solution) is in the title of your question:

> Passing the dimension of an Array as a Parameter

You can do this, i.e. create an appropriate array object, by using the [`Array.CreateInstance(Type, int[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k(v=vs.110).aspx) overload. IMHO, it will also work better if (but is not required that) you can consolidate the value/probability pairs into a single `struct`.

The other big caveat is that you won't get the benefit of compiler optimizations for accessing array elements. You'll have to use e.g. the `GetValue()` method, which will most likely prevent the compiler from accessing array elements directly (the optimization is theoretically possible, but seems unlikely to me).

So, for example, you could do something like:

```
Array Combine(ValueProbPair[] newDimension, Array previousDimensions)
{
    int[] rankLengths = new int[previousDimensions.Rank + 1];

    for (int j = 0; j < previousDimensions.Rank; j++)
    {
        rankLengths[j] = previousDimensions.GetLength(j);
    }

    rankLengths[previousDimensions.Rank] = newDimension.Length;

    Array result = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(ValueProbPair), rankLengths);

    // then fill in your matrix using GetValue and SetValue to
    // access individual array elements...

    // Finally, return the new multi-dimensional array:
    return result;
}
```

The various array method overloads that access elements use `params` array parameters, so you can without too much difficulty write code that can handle matrices of arbitrary dimension. E.g.:

```
IEnumerable<double> GetAllValues(Array source)
{
    int[] index = new int[source.Rank];

    while (true)
    {
        yield return (double)source.GetValue(index);

        int j = 0;
        while (++index[j] == source.GetLength(j))
        {
            index[j] = 0;
            if (++j == index.Length)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One last note: for dealing with value/probability, depending on your scenario you might actually find it makes more sense to do all this using dictionaries. There are different complications, but the basic building block would be `Dictionary<double, object>`, where the value is either `double` or another `Dictionary<double, object>`. Then if you are looking for e.g. a combined probability, you don't have to scan lists of values, but rather can just look them up directly as the key in the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much -- this was enormously helpful. I took your advice and re-implemented them the prob/val pairs as a struct. I'm going to finish an implementation using Array.CreateInstance (instead of C-style arrays) first and then I'll try a dictionary one for the practice.

I'm curious (if you know) how Array.CreateInstance implements the dimensionality parameter? Or where I might find that information? I'd enjoy knowing.

Will upvote this as soon as I have the rep =p. Thanks again!

Comment: _"how Array.CreateInstance implements the dimensionality parameter"_ -- I'm sorry, I'm afraid I am not understanding the question. What specifically are you trying to find out about that? Are you trying to understand how `params` works in C#? Or something else?

Comment: No, I'm wondering how if I were trying to implement my own flexible array class, could implement an overload like Createinstance(x, int32[]) so that the class can instantiate Arrays with arbitrary dimension (or more generally, wondering how to write constructors/classes so that non-type parameters may influence the type of the instance)

Comment: The `Array.CreateInstance()` method is `static`. I.e. it's not tied to an instance, so it has the freedom to use the `Type` parameter when creating an actual instance. By the time a _constructor_ is called, the type of the object has already been determined. Of course, you can use a `Type` object passed to the constructor to affect the type of objects _contained_ within the instance currently being constructed, but you can't affect that instance's type itself. If that doesn't answer your question, you probably should post an actual, new question with all the details for that specific issue.